# mysqltuner reports that I have "basic passwords in list". What does it mean?

Tags: mysql

I have a VPS running two Magento websites, and the performance is alright. However, there is always room for improvement.

Last week I installed mysqltuner on to the server, and let it run for 6 days. Yesterday I ran the report, and it highlighted various bits I should look to change. But in the report, it displayed this:

> [--] There are 612 basic passwords in the list.

The fact it's reported "basic passwords" concerns me. But in the recommendations at the end of the report it doesn't mention anything about them. It doesn't make me any less paranoid though.

So what are these basic passwords its referring to, and should it be something I seek to rectify?

Comment: It might have to do with: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html

Answer (score 2):

It is actually mysqltuner that has 612 basic passwords in its list.
See https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/blob/master/basic_passwords.txt